# AdMob rewarded videos always onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad

**My code is here**
I have test it on my device I also integrate this app on firebase.
but it never go to onRewarded it always call onRewardedFaild why sir?
can anyone help me.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK.
    MobileAds.initialize(this,APP_ID);

    mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
    loadRewardedVideoAd();

    // Create the "retry" button, which tries to show an interstitial between game plays.
    mRetryButton = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.retry_button));
    mRetryButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mRetryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startGame();
        }
    });

    // Create the "show" button, which shows a rewarded video if one is loaded.
    mShowVideoButton = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.watch_video));
    mShowVideoButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mShowVideoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showRewardedVideo();
        }
    });

    // Display current coin count to user.
    mCoinCountText = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.coin_count_text));
    mCoinCount = 0;
    mCoinCountText.setText("Coins: " + mCoinCount);

    startGame();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    pauseGame();
    mRewardedVideoAd.pause(this);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!mGameOver && mGamePaused) {
        resumeGame();
    }
    mRewardedVideoAd.resume(this);
}

private void pauseGame() {
    mCountDownTimer.cancel();
    mGamePaused = true;
}

private void resumeGame() {
    createTimer(mTimeRemaining);
    mGamePaused = false;
}

private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
    if (!mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd(AD_UNIT_ID, new AdRequest.Builder().build());
       /* AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("40C4DDA8F53FFA9BA5B61261E0CA28AB") // Test devices don't work work with rewarded video ads.
                .build();
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd(AD_UNIT_ID, adRequest);*/
    }
}

private void addCoins(int coins) {
    mCoinCount = mCoinCount + coins;
    mCoinCountText.setText("Coins: " + mCoinCount);
}

private void startGame() {
    // Hide the retry button, load the ad, and start the timer.
    mRetryButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mShowVideoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    loadRewardedVideoAd();
    createTimer(COUNTER_TIME);
    mGamePaused = false;
    mGameOver = false;
}

// Create the game timer, which counts down to the end of the level
// and shows the "retry" button.
private void createTimer(long time) {
    final TextView textView = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer));
    if (mCountDownTimer != null) {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
    }
    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(time * 1000, 50) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUnitFinished) {
            mTimeRemaining = ((millisUnitFinished / 1000) + 1);
            textView.setText("seconds remaining: " + mTimeRemaining);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                mShowVideoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            textView.setText("You Lose!");
            addCoins(GAME_OVER_REWARD);
            mRetryButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mGameOver = true;
        }
    };
    mCountDownTimer.start();
}

private void showRewardedVideo() {
    mShowVideoButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        mRewardedVideoAd.show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Preload the next video ad.
    loadRewardedVideoAd();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
    Toast.makeText(this,
            String.format(" onRewarded! currency: %s amount: %d", reward.getType(),
                    reward.getAmount()),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    addCoins(reward.getAmount());
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**I am using my Ad_Unit_ID Live not tested Device ID**

Comment: Did you just create the Ad Unit ID? It can take up to 24 hours until the Ad Unit ID is active. Do test ads show when you enable them?

Comment: Ohhhh Okay Thanks Man you save my time,

Comment: I will Inform you here if I still have some problem.

Comment: I was just enable it today round about 5'O Clock

Comment: show your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Comment: here is manifest.xml

Comment: @Syed Tehrim Abbas did you resolved your problem?

Comment: Yes, It's resolved @MuhammadNatiq